# SharePoint Workflow that creates a column in a list

Tags: 2013, workflow

This is a general workflow question.  I know that workflows can put a value in an existing column.  But can a workflow actually create a new column in an existing list/list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 2013 style workflows can call SharePoint REST API web services. While the example is for a JavaScript call, this article shows how it can be done:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182(v=office.15)

Let me know if you need the workflow steps.

Comment: Thanks - WF steps wouldn't hurt, if you had them available.